# How to prepend filename to last lines of files found through find command in Unix

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, find

I have a requirement where I need to display the last lines of all the files under a directory in the format

```
filename: lastline
```

I found the following code

```
find /user/directory/* -name "*txt" -mtime 0   -type f -exec awk '{s=$0};END{print FILENAME, ": ",s}' {} \;
```

But I read this reads the entire file each time. The files in my directory are huge so I cannot afford this. Do I have any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `tail` as in the other answers is good. Now, you can wrap all this into the `find` command.

If your `find` supports the `-printf` command:

```
find /user/directory/ -name "*txt" -mtime 0 -type f -printf '%p: ' -exec tail -1 {} \;
```

If your `find` doesn't support the `-printf` command:

```
find /user/directory/ -name "*txt" -mtime 0 -type f -exec printf '%s: ' {} \; -exec tail -1 {} \;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
find /user/directory/* -name "*txt" -mtime 0 -type f | while IFS= read -r file
do
    echo -n "$file: "
    tail -1 "$file"
done
```

The important change is that tail -1 won't read the whole file, but reads small portions from the end and increases them until it has found the complete last line.

Comment: Or, avoiding metacharacters in `echo` (which tend to be problematic if you need to switch between shells), `echo "$file: $(tail -1 $file)"`.

Comment: Always use `while IFS= read -r file` unless you have a specific purpose in mind and fully understand the caveats.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's much better that way and I changed it in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the directory name:

```
for f in $(/bin/ls directory/*.txt); do 
    echo "$f: $(tail -1 $f)"
done
```

will do the trick. More generally,

```
for f in $(find /user/directory -type f -name "*.txt"); do
    echo "$f: $(tail -1 $f)"
done
```

will work as well. The program `tail` will start reading the file from the end, and `tail -n` will only read the last `n` lines of a specified file.

Comment: Use `for f in directory/*.txt` or `find /user/directory -type f -name "*.txt" | while IFS= read -r f` instead of the above commands which will fail for file names that contain spaces. If the file names can contain newlines look into an `xargs -0` solution.